# XDB Connection Reset Errot

Tags: emc

xDB server was running successfully in our environment.

But after some days, we are getting "Connection reset" exception.

What could be the possible reason and how we can solve this issue?

Thanks & Regards

Arpan

Answer (score 0):

Without further information about your application and the way you use xDB it is very difficult to answer this, but "Connection reset" type of errors usually occur in two situations:

- The server-side closed the socket, for instance as a result of an unexpected error/crash.
- There was no communication on the socket for long time and the OS closed the channel because of the TCP keep-alive timeout (which I believe is usually 2 hours).

Can you describe in more detail the circumstances when you get the error? Is the server still operational after you start getting the error? If so, are you perhaps pooling xDB sessions and reusing them after potentially long periods of inactivity?